# How do I get more pets?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When the update with the pets came out I received a free pet. Since then I have opened a fair few lunchboxes with none entailing a pet. Is the only way to get more pets to buy them?

Answer (score 4):

Pet carriers can be bought from the shop in packs the same way as additional lunchboxes can be bought.

[image]

[image]

They can also be obtained as objective awards, similar to how a Mr. Handy can be obtained.

[image]

I've not experienced it myself, but it has been mentioned elsewhere that pets can be found in lunchboxes - but it's a very rare occurrence.

Comment: I have completed probably hundreds of objectives and have never seen a Mr. Handy as a reward.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I've been playing for several months, and just got my first Mr. Handy reward last week.

Answer (score 1):

Pets can be found in lunchboxes,(though rare) and bought in packs from the shop, I've heard rumour that they can be found in the wasteland,but that is yet to be confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one pet from a lunchbox, but I cannot confirm its rarity since there are no accessible statistics on the pets yet.